# Third party filing DS160 US B2 tourist visa

Tags: b1-b2-visas

"Other people can assist you with your visa application. Note that under U.S. law (22 C.F.R. 41.103) you must electronically sign and submit your own application unless you qualify for an exemption. Even if someone else helped you complete the application, you (the applicant) must click the “Sign Application” button, or your application may not be accepted."

in addition to above i read somewhere that third parties not related to applicant cannot even fill online form even if submit button is pressed by applicant.

secondly when is the visa fees actually need to pay , after submitting ds160 or at the time of booking biometrics and interview appointment.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are applying from India. In this case you will [pay the visa fee](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-niv-paymentinfo.asp) *after* submitting the DS-160 form, and *before* scheduling the appointment. Someone else can make the payment for you, but for the chosen payment method you need a unique number in order to continue to schedule the appointment.

The process is different if you are applying from some other country. In that case, check the US consulate web site for that country or [ustraveldocs.com](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/).

Comment: okies, but can a third party not related, can fill and press submitt button ?

Comment: @Footloose It's not allowed, but you probably wouldn't get caught. That said, you probably don't want to allow someone else to fill in the application for you. You would not know what is in it, and we have seen many cases where a visa agent intentionally put information on a visa application that caused the person to be refused the visa. It's not a good idea.

Comment: thanks now when i select tourist visa under non immigrant category i get confusing options, business or  tourism(b1/b2)  tourism or medical(b2), since my purpose is purely tourism, these extra words business and medical are confusing

Comment: @Footloose You should just apply for B1/B2 and don't worry about it. This is the visa that virtually everyone gets.

Comment: oh. my friend who finished his ds160 form today, had selected tourism or medical b2 visawill he get rejected

Comment: This is now far away from the original question.